# which AMI image we have to use for ECS cluster as Amazon ECS-optimized AMI is getting depricated

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I saw this document which says Amazon ECS-optimized AMI is getting depricated and they are not going to maintain this any more.

So if I want to create a new ECS cluster and use ec2 instad of fargte which ami image should i use for ec2 image creation with auto-scaling?

doc reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-optimized_AMI.html

Answer (score 1):

Only "Amazon Linux 1" based ECS images are being deprecated, all others are still supported. Simply scroll down on that page to the table for "Amazon Linux 2" based images and use that for your ASG.